# How to `import FreeCAD` in CLI (python)

Tags: debian, command-line, python, cad

How can I `import FreeCAD` from the python console?

I'm trying to write a script that can manipulate a given FreeCAD file, but I can't even get FreeCAD imported into the python console on a system where FreeCAD is installed.

```
user@disp7637:~$ sudo dpkg -l | grep -i freecad
ii  freecad                                       0.19.1+dfsg1-2+deb11u1             all          Extensible Open Source CAx program
ii  freecad-common                                0.19.1+dfsg1-2+deb11u1             all          Extensible Open Source CAx program - common files
ii  freecad-python3                               0.19.1+dfsg1-2+deb11u1             amd64        Extensible Open Source CAx program - Python 3 binaries
ii  libfreecad-python3-0.19                       0.19.1+dfsg1-2+deb11u1             amd64        Extensible Open Source CAx program - Python 3 library files
user@disp7637:~$ 

user@disp7637:~$ python3
Python 3.9.2 (default, Feb 28 2021, 17:03:44) 
[GCC 10.2.1 20210110] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import FreeCAD
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'FreeCAD'
>>> import freecad
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'freecad'
>>>
```

I am running Debian 11

```
user@disp7637:~$ cat /etc/issue
Debian GNU/Linux 11 \n \l

user@disp7637:~$
```

How can I `import FreeCAD` in the python console?

Comment: See also https://forum.freecad.org/viewtopic.php?p=691304

Comment: I reported this as a bug to the Debian maintainer of `freecad-python3` https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=1049933

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I think the post you're referring to is overselling things a bit when it says

> There is also possibility to import FreeCAD as a Python module but this is more complex.

FreeCAD in itself *embeds* python to give access to its internal state to scripts running within in the FreeCAD process.

So, things like import order start to matter. Anyways, here we go:

Because the modules are so interlinked with FreeCAD, they're not installed to python standard module paths; instead, you will find them in `/usr/lib/freecad-python3/lib` on debian. So,

```py
from sys import path as syspath
syspath.append("/usr/lib/freecad-python3/lib")
syspath.append("/usr/share/freecad/Mod/")

import FreeCAD
import Draft
```

By the way, other distros more stubbornly use architectural names for these subfolders, so on Fedora and related distros, the path happens to be `/usr/lib64/freecad/lib64`, at least on x86_64.

Comment: I used `import sys; sys.path.append()`, but it works! Any reason to use `syspath` instaed of `sys.path()`?

Comment: I thought it might be confusing to have different things called "path", as FreeCAD contains a `Path` module.

Comment: It wasn't in the question, but you'll also need to add `/usr/share/freecad/Mod/` to your syspath to add tools like the Draft workbench (eg `import Draft`). Would you mind adding this to your answer?